# Reading a text file and get the result of only the last integer per line in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, mpi, scanf

Okay I was given a text file that has 3 integers per line. The first is a document number, the second a word number, and the 3rd is the number of times that word appears in that document.

Ex.

- 1  61  2
- 1  76  1
- 2  89  3
- 3  68  2

My class is to use MPI as a way of splitting up the text file among nodes in our school's cluster. I need to check if each document does or does not contain a word that appears X number of times and then return the number of documents that do. I'm new to C/C++ and just need to know what the easiest way of doing that would be.

Comment: homework? May be you should try something and then ask for help when you are stuck.

Comment: I have I've been using fscanf to read in integers but I'm not sure how I can read only the first and last or just the last integer in each triple

Comment: could you please share your work?

Comment: "I'm new to C" -- It is tagged C++, are you sure you're using C++, or is it pure C?

Comment: I've been using both, it is a c++ compiler. Sorry if I'm being really nooby I just picked up c last week

Comment: I asked because if it is C++ and you're allowed to use the standard library, then you can use `fstream operator >>`. Seeing as it's also tagged `fscanf` I think you might only be allowed C code.

Comment: No I am allowed to do both, I started the project using only c and found out shortly after. Didn't really know there was an alternative to fscanf

Comment: @Fawzan I agree with my machang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just need to know what the easiest way of doing that would be

I think you may try the following:

- Open the txt file.
- Read line-by-len.
- Use `strtok` to get each token (string) from each line.
- Use `atoi` to convert the last string token to an `int`.

As a very crude implementation of how to extract the last one, see below as an example:

```
char str[] = "3 68 2";
char *items[3] = { NULL };
char *pch;

pch = strtok(str, " ");
printf( "pch = %s\n", pch );    // first token
pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
printf( "pch = %s\n", pch );    // second token
pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
printf( "pch = %s\n", pch );    // third token

int i3 = atoi( pch );
printf( "i3 = %d\n", i3 );
```

Comment: How do you convert only the last string token per line?

Comment: You need to skip the first two tokens. `strtok` can do that.

Comment: Btw, I added a crude implementation of extracting the last number via `strtok`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as a base to work on. I didn't want to solve your homework problem directly.

```
std::ifstream file("myfile");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line)) // for each line in the file, store it in variable line
{
    std::istringstream ss(line); // load the line into a string stream for processing
    int i; // variable for storing the integers
    while (ss >> i) // for each integer successfully extracted
    {
        std::cout << i << ' '; // print it out
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Be sure to check your solution with the following cases:

- empty file
- empty line (no numbers)
- 1 number on line
- line containing non-numbers?